# How can I find out which alternate regular expression matched my string

Tags: python, regex

If I have a regular expression which has a `|` operator separating two possible patterns. Is it possible to find which pattern was the one that matched my string?

For example, if I have the pattern `([cC]at|[dD]og)` and I find a match in the string `clifford is a dog`. Can I then look back to see that the pattern `[dD]og` was the successful match and not the alternative: `[cC]at`.

I understand that I could try to match each alternate pattern individually and then just take the successful ones but I am wondering if there is another solution that doesn't require a match attempt for each pattern (I'm hoping to apply this in a situation where I'm trying to match several hundred patterns at once)

Comment: keep them in two separate groups `([cC]at)|([dD]og)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two different groups and check its index, like this:

```
([cC]at)|([dD]og)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mJ2yD2/1)**

Match information

```
MATCH 1
    Group 2.    [14-17] `dog`
MATCH 2
    Group 1.    [33-36] `cat`
```

Btw, if for some reason you have to group the whole alternation you can use a non capturing group like this:

```
(?:([cC]at)|([dD]og))
```

Comment: Thank you @Federico , you answered my question perfectly. I can't believe I didn't think to use groups